# get action to happen, only when submit button is pressed

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

i have some code that will post to the users wall, however, at the minute it will post when the page is loaded, i need it to post only when the 'post to my wall button is submitted.

here is my code:

```
<div align="center">
<form method="GET" action="translate.php">
<textarea name="status2" cols="50" rows="5"<input type="text"/>
<?php echo str_ireplace(array     ('old','awkward','all','again','behind','along','alright','hello','among','children','yes','child','kids','food','barnard castle','beer','book','blow','beautiful','bird','burst','brown','burn','boots'), 
array ('auld', 'aakwad', 'aall','agyen','ahint','alang','alreet','alreet','amang','bairns','aye','bairn','bairns','bait','barney','beor','beuk','blaa','bonny','bord','borst','broon','bourn','byeuts'),$status); ?> 

</textarea><br>

<input type="submit" value="post to wall"
// i did try my wall code here but it still posted on page load
 />
</form>

</div>

<?php

$args = array(
    'message'   => 'Hello World',
    'link'      => 'http://apps.facebook.com/geordie-status/',
    'caption'   => 'Translate from English to Geordie'
    );
$post_id = $facebook->api("/$uid/feed", "post", $args);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `name` attribute to your `input` tag. and use `isset` for check if the user pressed the submit button.

```
        <input type="submit" value="post to wall" name="submit"
        // i did try my wall code here but it still posted on page load
         />
        </form>

</div>

    <?php    
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $args = array(
            'message'   => 'Hello World',
            'link'      => 'http://apps.facebook.com/geordie-status/',
            'caption'   => 'Translate from English to Geordie'
            );
        $post_id = $facebook->api("/$uid/feed", "post", $args);
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: lmao, i just figured this out but changed the form action to post.php and basically added the above if into post.php. Thanks anyway, you still get the answer tick :D

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code for the posting to the wall inside translate.php since that is the page listed in the form action. When the form gets submitted, values will be passed as parameters to translate.php then you can use $_GET to fetch them and execute the code that writes to the wall.

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned, this code is inside translate.php. What i need is the php code to execute only when the submit button is clicked. after i figure that out, i can focus on the remainder of my issues. Thanks

Comment: Well you can add an <input type="hidden" id="isSubmitted" value="true" /> in your form, then check if $_GET['isSubmitted'] == 'true' and if so then you know the form submit button was actually clicked and data is being posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your browser re-sends data each time the page is reloaded.

There are 2 approaches:

- Redirect user to the same page, so sent data will be cleared (`header("Location: asd")`)
- Store some hash in session, make a hidden input and check whether the hash is right. Change the hash when the form is correctly submitted.

Comment: not sure what any of that means to be honest. The code above is my translate.php page. Before this, the user uses my index.php and the data inputted there is sent using POST into translate.php. the textarea is used to display the data after it has been changed and the user can hit 'submit' so the data is posted to their wall.